# Equalize occurrence of characters across all lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have lines of output I would like to pipe into commands to alter its final form.

I am trying to look at each line and determine who has the maximum number of a specific character `%`. Then I want to make sure all lines have the same number of `%` so you just add however many `%` are missing to the end of the line. An example input being piped in:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 %x 4
%r %c %s 4
1 2 3 4
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
1 2 %x 4 %z %z
%r %c %s 4
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
```

It would also be acceptable to just have a maximum a priori and just pad the string to that number. I would imagine this would break if some line had more instances of that character than your maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perl is good for this:

```
perl -lne '
    push @lines, $_; $n = tr/%/%/; push @n, $n; $max = $n if $n > $max
  } END {
    print $lines[$_] . " %z" x ($max - $n[$_]) for (0 .. $#lines);
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to solve this by using input field separator as `%`:

```
awk -F% -v n=3 '{rn = n+1 -NF; for (i=1; i<=rn; i++) $0 = $0 OFS "%z"} 1' file

1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
1 2 %x 4 %z %z
%r %c %s 4
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution (for any number of `%` occurrences):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ r = gsub("%","",$0); if(r>max) max=r; a[NR]=r; next }
     a[FNR] < max{ for(i=max-a[FNR];i--;) $0=$0" %z" }1' file file
```

---

- `r` - number of replacements of `%` character
- `max` - will eventually contain the maximal number of `%` char occurrences for all the lines

---

The output:

```
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
1 2 %x 4 %z %z
%r %c %s 4
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file |
awk -F'%' '
    { maxNF = (maxNF>NF ? maxNF : NF); a[NR]=$0; nf[NR]=NF }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
            printf "%s", a[i]
            for (j=nf[i]+1; j<=maxNF; j++) {
                printf "%s%sz", OFS, FS
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
'
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
1 2 %x 4 %z %z
%r %c %s 4
1 2 3 4 %z %z %z
```

The `cat file |` is obviously only present to demonstrate piped input because you said `I would like to pipe into commands...`